# Concatenating JSX fragments in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am working on a component in React which is supposed to render out a message which can have an arbitrary amount of links in it. The `props` of this component takes in a `message` which is a `string`, and `tags`, which is an object array of type `Tag`. A sample of the `tag` type can be seen below:

```
{
    index: 6,
    tagged_object_id: 4,
    tag_type: "object",
    tag_text: "world!"
}
```

If the component were to be created with `props` containing the tag above, and a message of `Hello`, I would like the render function to have the following output:

```
<p> Hello <Link to="/object/4">world!</Link></p>
```

This output should of course work for arbitrary amounts of tags.

I'm stuck on actually producing this output with JSX.

I have attempted to do so below, but obviously the code does not work. How can I produce this output in my `render()` function?

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './Message.css';

class Message extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.formattedMessage = this.formatMessage(this.props.message, this.props.tags);
    }

    formatMessage(message, tags) {
        var returnVal = []
        var sortedTags = tags.sort(this.compareTags)
        var lastIndex = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < sortedTags.length; i++) {
            returnVal.push(message.substring(lastIndex, sortedTags[i].index))
            returnVal.push(<Link to={"/"+sortedTags[i].tag_type+"s/"+sortedTags[i].tagged_object_id}/>)
            lastIndex = sortedTags[i].index
        }
        returnVal.push(message.substring(lastIndex, message.length))
        return returnVal
    }

    compareTags(a, b) {
        if (a.index < b.index) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a.index > b.index) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.formattedMessage)
        return (
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <pre className={styles.message}>
                    <p>{this.formattedMessage}</p>
                </pre>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default Message;
```

Comment: You should call `this.formattedMessage = this.formatMessage(this.props.message, this.props.tags);` in the render function just before you return the DOM. I would also pull out some of your `formatMessage` code into the render, the part where you actually create the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, the following code should function the way you expect.

Of course, you can also sort the tags array prior to the return of the render function, if you so choose to do so.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Message extends Component {
  render() {
    const { message = '', tags = [] } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          tags.map((tag, index) => (
            <p>{message} <Link to={`/${tag.tag_type}/${tag.tagged_object_id}`}>{tag.tag_text}</Link></p>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Message;
```